# python regex not matching decoded unicode string

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I've compiled my regex using:

```
number_re = re.compile(ur'(?<![-_\.])\b([0-9]+|[0-9]+[0-9-_\.]*[0-9]+)\b(?![-_\.])'), re.UNICODE)
```

and it manages to match the **1990-1991** in the following string:

```
mystring = 'フットボールリーグ1990-1991'
match = number_re.search(mystring)
>>> <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x25e1918>
match.group()
>>> '1990-1991'
```

but when the string is decoded (or when it's passed into a function)

```
mystring = 'フットボールリーグ1990-1991'.decode('utf-8')
>>> u'\u30d5\u30c3\u30c8\u30dc\u30fc\u30eb\u30ea\u30fc\u30b01990-1991'
match = number_re.search(mystring)
```

the matching no longer occurs, I'm guessing it has to do with the boundaries '\b' not matching because it looks like one continuous string but I'm not exactly sure.

I think that I've put all the unicode requirements (compiled with 're.UNICODE' flag and also put 'ur' in my regex string.  The last thing I'm going to try is the [Python regex library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) that everyone says is good, but I'd like to know what's wrong with my current stuff! :).

Comment: don't mix Unicode and non-Unicode strings (bytes). [you cannot match a Unicode string with a byte pattern or vice-versa](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> \b

There isn't a word boundary between the letter `グ` and the number `1`—they are both alphanumerics. When Unicode-aware regex is being used this is correctly handled, hence no match. If you don't want to treat katakana and other non-ASCII letters as being alphanums, remove the `re.UNICODE` flag which controls this behaviour.

When you send a byte string to a regex that was compiled from a Unicode string, it is automatically decoded. For some reason it seems to be decoded as ISO-8859-1 (rather than, say, `sys.getdefaultencoding()`)... don't know why that is, but implicit encode/decode is in general evil to be avoided.

The UTF-8 byte sequence for `グ`, when mis-decoded as ISO-8859-1, comes out as `ã[control char]°`. The degree sign is not an alphanum so you get a match.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew that word boundary was fishy, haha.